# How to do feature extraction using Gabor filter?

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, machine-learning, feature-extraction

i have a set of grayscale images (96,96) and i want to apply gabor filter to the entire images pixel by pixel. i heard that gabor filters give maximum variance in data and insensitive to orientation and lightning.

Here is a piece of code i use. I applied the filter to one image and output data is Image+Gabor filter applied.

I tried to feed this gabor filter applied image to machine learning algorithm and there is no change or improvement in the classification accuracy. Why?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pylab as pl

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv',header=0)

df['Image'] = df['Image'].apply(lambda im: np.fromstring(im, sep=' ') )
X = np.vstack (df['Image'].values) 

X = X.astype(np.uint8)
X = X.reshape(-1,96,96)


def image_histogram_equalization(image, number_bins=256):
    # from http://www.janeriksolem.net/2009/06/histogram-equalization-with-python-and.html

    # get image histogram
    image_histogram, bins = np.histogram(image.flatten(), number_bins, normed=True)
    cdf = image_histogram.cumsum() # cumulative distribution function
    cdf = 255 * cdf / cdf[-1] # normalize

    # use linear interpolation of cdf to find new pixel values
    image_equalized = np.interp(image.flatten(), bins[:-1], cdf)

    return image_equalized.reshape(image.shape), cdf

def build_filters():
 filters = []
 ksize = 31
 for theta in np.arange(0, np.pi, np.pi / 16):
  kern = cv2.getGaborKernel((ksize, ksize), 4.0, theta, 10.0, 0.5, 0, ktype=cv2.CV_32F)
  kern /= 1.5*kern.sum()
  filters.append(kern)
 return filters

def process(img, filters):
 accum = np.zeros_like(img)
 for kern in filters:
  fimg = cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_8UC3, kern)
  np.maximum(accum, fimg, accum)
 return accum

filters = []

for k in xrange(5):
 img = X[k]

 X[k, :, :] = image_histogram_equalization(X[k, :,:])[0]

 filters = build_filters()
 filters = np.asarray(filters)
 print filters.shape
 res1 = process(img, filters)
 cv2.imshow('result', res1)
 cv2.waitKey(0)
 cv2.destroyAllWindows()

f = np.asarray(filters)
print 'Filters', f.shape
```

It outputs the filters with 16 orientations (for one particular frequency)

```
(16, 31, 31) - Image 1
(16, 31, 31) - Image 2
(16, 31, 31) - Image 3
..
```

[image: Gabor filter applied on grayscale face]

Sorry my question may be premature, but i am curious to know more.

1. what should i feed to the machine learning classifier? is it only gabor filter data or the filter itself applied to all images.
2. How do i tweak the above code to get filter responses for 10 different frequencies? i want to extract 16x10=160 filters for every image.
3. i have set the gabor kernel size to 31x31 for 96x96 pixel images. Is this correct?

Comment: 1. What machine learning algorithm are you trying to provide input to? What sort of classification task is it trying to do?
2. You would need another loop to control the frequency of the Gabor kernels. The frequency term is the lambda argument which comes after theta ( = 10.0 in your code). You might also want to read up on how sigma interacts with lambda to make sure your full frequency range works as you would expect.
3. Try some other sizes to see how they affect the output? That is a large kernel for such small images (which risks weird border artifacts), but it depends on your input image

Comment: I am doing a linear regression. What is the ideal kernel

Comment: Okay, that still does not give me enough details. How were you doing linear regression without applying a filter (you said the Gabor filter results gave you no benefits)? What were you passing in as your data vector in both situations? Without knowing more details of your application it becomes very difficult to know how to advise you, and the best answer may very well be to just test a lot of different parameters and see which ones work best.

Comment: How to apply Gabor filter into the linear regression? Please explain with details. Please, Give source if necessary for better understand.